# Unsupported operand types CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, fatal-error, croogo

I have a **CakePHP** project running on other server **PHP 5.6** but here this same app is not running on **PHP 5.6 / 7.0**.

I am using **Croogo** with **CakePHP**.

It's showing me debug error like below:

> Error: [Error] Unsupported operand types
>       Stack Trace:
>       #0 /Vendor/cakephp/cakephp/lib/Cake/Core/CakePlugin.php(282): include()
>       #1 /Vendor/cakephp/cakephp/lib/Cake/Core/CakePlugin.php(201): CakePlugin::_includeFile('/var/www/vhosts...', true)
>       #2 /Vendor/cakephp/cakephp/lib/Cake/Core/CakePlugin.php(121): CakePlugin::bootstrap('Acl')
>       #3 /Vendor/cakephp/cakephp/lib/Cake/Core/CakePlugin.php(94): CakePlugin::load('Acl', Array)
>       #4 /Vendor/croogo/croogo/Extensions/Lib/CroogoPlugin.php(656): CakePlugin::load(Array, Array)
>       #5 /Vendor/croogo/croogo/Croogo/Config/croogo_bootstrap.php(126): CroogoPlugin::load(Array)
>       #6 /Vendor/croogo/croogo/Croogo/Config/bootstrap.php(8): require_once('/var/www/vhosts...')
>       #7 /Vendor/cakephp/cakephp/lib/Cake/Core/CakePlugin.php(282): include('/var/www/vhosts...')
>       #8 /Vendor/cakephp/cakephp/lib/Cake/Core/CakePlugin.php(201): CakePlugin::_includeFile('/var/www/vhosts...', false)
>       #9 /Vendor/cakephp/cakephp/lib/Cake/Core/CakePlugin.php(121): CakePlugin::bootstrap('Croogo')
>       #10 /Config/bootstrap.php(78): CakePlugin::load('Croogo', Array)
>       #11 /Vendor/cakephp/cakephp/lib/Cake/Core/Configure.php(98): include('/var/www/vhosts...')
>       #12 /Vendor/cakephp/cakephp/lib/Cake/bootstrap.php(432): Configure::bootstrap(true)
>       #13 /webroot/index.php(90): include('/var/www/vhosts...')
>       #14 {main}

It is from my tmp/logs/error.log file

Is there any fix?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try debugging this place: `/Vendor/cakephp/cakephp/lib/Cake/Core/CakePlugin.php(282): include() #1`. See which file it's trying to include when failing and what's in it.